# Qooxdoo form elements and getSelection()

Tags: qooxdoo

Here's my code:

```
var sb = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();

sb.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("English") );
sb.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Nederlands") );
sb.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Deutsch") );
sb.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("français") );
sb.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Српски") );
```

How do I use setSelection() to select "Deutsch", and what if the items are numeric values? Can I also set values for these labels or is SelectBox() limited to labels?

For example:

```
value: en, label: English
value: de, label: Deutsch
etc.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the example code below.

You can specify a model with each ListItem for storing additional information. It can act as value property on form items for example. See http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.0.x/apiviewer/#qx.ui.form.ListItem

```
  var selectBox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();

  selectBox.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("English", null, "en" ));
  selectBox.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Nederlands", null, "nl" ));
  var defaultItem = new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Deutsch", null, "de" );
  selectBox.add(defaultItem );
  selectBox.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("français", null, "fr"));
  selectBox.add( new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Српски", null, "ru"));

  selectBox.setSelection([defaultItem]);
  selectBox.addListener("changeSelection", function(e) {

    //Read model data from listitem
    this.debug("changeSelection: " + e.getData()[0].getModel());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be useful for you too:

```
var sb = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
var a = ["English", "Nederlands", "Deutsch", "Français", "Српски"];
var model = new qx.data.Array(a);
var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(model, sb);
controller.setSelection(model.slice(0,3));
```

At last line model.slice(0,3) returns subarray of model with three elements: from "English" to "Deutsch". And last element in this subarray will be "selected" by default.

See "Data Binding" in qooxdoo's manual for details.